# Java thinks I want to convert char to String using Integer.parseInt()

Tags: java, parseint

I get the error message `error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String 
return Integer.parseInt(cases2[0]);`

but my code is:

```
public static int standingOvation(String cases){

    char[] cases2 = cases.toCharArray();
    return Integer.parseInt(cases2[0]);
}
```

Why am I getting the error if i'm clearly trying to convert `cases` (which is passed in as `"11111"`) to an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return Integer.parseInt("" + cases2[0]);
```

By adding to the empty string `""` you convert to a string, which is the right type for `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: @ralphie9224 You can also do `String.valueOf(cases2[0])` to convert a `char` to a `String`, but the `"" +`  trick is useful to know as it converts *anything* to a `String`. It is a bit hacky though.

Comment: @pbabcdefp `String.valueOf` also converts anything to `String`.

Answer (score 3):

**The construct `cases2[0]` will pick the first character out of the `cases2` string.**

`Integer.parseInt()` requires a `String` argument, not a `char`.

Comment: got it. so I guess I should use `Character.getNumericValue(cases2[0])` instead?

Comment: @ralphie9224 Yes, you should.