# Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to String

Tags: java

```
package kreki;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hungry {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String input;
        char ans;
        Scanner Hungry = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Are You Hungry?");
        input = Hungry.next();
        ans = input.charAt(0);
        if(ans == "Y") {
            System.out.println("Eat");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Starve");
        }
        Hungry.close();
    }
}
```

I'm getting Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to String.
How can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java thinks I want to convert char to String using Integer.parseInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583655/java-thinks-i-want-to-convert-char-to-string-using-integer-parseint)

Answer (score 4):

It can be hard to  spot for new in Java/programming overall.

Error is here:

```
if(ans == "Y") {
```

Change double quotes to single one

```
if(ans == 'Y') {
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `if`:

```
  if(ans == 'Y') {
        System.out.println("Eat");
    }
```

you just need so change to single quote, because those are used for `char` symbols in Java. When you're using double quotes, Java is considering it a `String`, therefore a mismatch of types on comparison.